# how to show matches and missing values from three tables in sql joins

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to compare three lists. Here is my desired output:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|user      |equipmenttype |equipmentmodel |equipmentid |equipmentmac |result     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Bob1234   |Laptop        |Lenovo Y2      |12345678    |82FB1234     |MATCH      |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Bob1234   |Phone         |HTC M8         |null        |AF1234M8     |MATCH      |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Bob1234   |Phone         |HTC M9         |null        |AF895213M9   |ADDITIONAL |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Sally5485 |Phone         |iPhone 6s      |null        |AP12346S     |MATCH      |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Sally5485 |Desktop       |Mac Pro        |11223344556 |MP124523     |MISSING    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If equipment reported matches master list, display everything with result as "match"

If equipment is on master list but missed being reported, display everything with result as "missing"

If equipment isn't on master list but reported, display everything with result as "additional"

Three tables:

**MasterEquipmentList Table**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|user      |equipmenttype |equipmentmodel |equipmentid |equipmentmac |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|Bob1234   |Laptop        |Lenovo Y2      |12345678    |82FB1234     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|Bob1234   |Phone         |HTC M8         |null        |AF1234M8     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|Sally5485 |Phone         |iPhone 6s      |null        |AP12346S     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|Sally5485 |Desktop       |Mac Pro        |11223344556 |MP124523     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**ComputerReportedList Table**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|user      |equipmenttype |equipmentmodel |equipmentid |equipmentmac |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|Bob1234   |Laptop        |Lenovo Y2      |12345678    |82FB1234     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**PhoneReportedList Table**

```
---------------------------------------------------------
|user      |equipmenttype |equipmentmodel |equipmentmac |
---------------------------------------------------------
|Bob1234   |Phone         |HTC M8         |AF1234M8     |
---------------------------------------------------------
|Bob1234   |Phone         |HTC M9         |AF895213M9   |
---------------------------------------------------------
|Sally5485 |Phone         |iPhone 6s      |AP12346S     |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

I am struggling with how to join everything together because there isn't a unique key. The end user is reporting on this, so if they put the equipmentserial in the equipmentmac field, it could cause the data to show as missing. The only unique key I see that I can join on is the user name.

Can someone help me get a start on how to achieve what it is I am looking for?

Comment: None of your table schema are matching up with your sample data.  It would be much more clear if you presented the data in table form to match the column names with the data.

Comment: Good call out. I have edited the post with the changes suggested!

Answer (score 0):

i would configure this as 1 table for equipment, 1 table for user, 1 table to join the 2, and a view or stored procedure to get the output you want.

```
create table dbo.equipment (EquipId int primary key identity(1,1)
  , EquipmentMac varchar(100)
  , EquipmentType varchar(20)
  , EquipmentSerial varchar(20)
  , EquipmentModel varchar(100)
  , IsAdditionalEquipment bit not null default(0)
)

create table dbo.users (UserId int primary key identity(1,1)
  , Username varchar(20)
)

create table dbo.jn_userequipment (EquipId int
  , UserId int
  , IsMissing bit not null default(0)
  , constraint PK_jnuserequipment primary key (equipid int, userid int)
)

create view dbo.vw_equipment as
select u.Username
, e.EquipmentType
, e.EquipmentModel
, e.EquipmentMac
, e.EquipmentSerial
, case when e.IsAdditionalEquipment = 1 then 'Additional'
  when j.IsMissing = 1 then 'Missing'
  else 'Match' end as [result]
from dbo.equipment as e
inner join dbo.jn_userequipment as j on j.equipid = e.equipid
inner join dbo.users as u on u.userid = j.userid;
```

add all of your equipment data and master list to the equipment table, use the IsAdditionalEquipment flag to mark which things which were not part of the master list.

i went with the assumption that equipment would go missing from someone's possession, so i put the IsMissing bit in the join table, but if you don't care who had it last it could just as easily go into the equipment table.

the above is a basic flexible starting point that will be really easy to query:

```
select * from dbo.vw_equipment where username = 'Bob1234'
select * from dbo.vw_equipment where equipmenttype = 'Phone'
select * from dbo.vw_equipment where [result] = 'Missing'
```

to your point about people putting the serial into the mac field, there's 2 ways to deal with that: user education and error checking. otherwise yes, if they enter a serial into the wrong field and it searches on that, they're going to receive bad results -- that's sort of the whole bane of developers' existence.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure I have fully understand your problem, I will try to reword:

- You have a "registred" equipment list (`MasterEquipmentList`)
- You have an "inventory"/effective equipement list. This list is split over two equipment kind (`ComputerReportedList` and `PhoneReportedList`)
- You wish to compare "registred" and "inventory" ones for whatever.

If all is clear here is what you have to do:

1) Build a merge "inventory" list (also called "polymorphic query")

```
select user, equipmentmodel, equipmentmac, equipmentid      from ComputerReportedList
union all
select user, equipmentmodel, equipmentmac, null equipmentid from PhoneReportedList
```

2) Make a [Sort-merge join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort-merge_join) (in french, we call it 'appareillage'). This is achieved in SQL using `FULL OUTER JOIN`. I assume you can join (match) on both `user` and `equipmentmac`.

```
select
  coalesce(m.user          , r.user)         name            ,
  m.equipmenttype                                            ,
  coalesce(r.equipmentmodel, m.equipmentmodel) equipmentmodel,
  coalesce(r.equipmentid   , m.equipmentid)    equipmentid   ,
  coalesce(m.equipmentmac  , r.equipmentmac)   equipmentmac  ,
  m.equipmentserial                                          ,
  case
    when m.user is null then 'additional'
    when r.user is null then 'missing'
    else                     'match'
  end result
from
  MasterEquipmentList m
  full outer join
  ReportedEquipmentList r on
        r.user         = m.user
    and r.equipmentmac = m.equipmentmac
```

Some remarks:

- From your `ComputerReportedList` description, only four fields are described but five are shown in sample
- From your `PhoneReportedList` description, same with three in description versus five in sample ...
- You don't have specified behaviour whatever "identity" (`user`, `equipmentmac`) currently match but "description" (`equipmentmodel`, `equipmentid`) don't. I have assumed "inventory" data have priority over "registred" one.

As you may have understood, the key point is "data correlation" which rely on "data identity". This last one is a primary requirement about "data management" whatever you're doing relational DB, inventory, requirement engineering, REST service, etc.

If you can't specify "data identity" at the moment, THEN STOP THINKING ABOUT YOUR ASKING FEATURE. And put priority on this. Most material inventory systems have their own internal references, which often are glued on material.

You may also correlate data using manufacturer, part number (P/N) and serial number (S/N). P/N is an alphanumeric and reliable identifier for a "vendor model" ; for example the "Samsung Galaxy S2" (commercial name) phone is identified by "GT-I9100". S/N (like serial production chain) is an incremental number unique for each physical device. This number may be unique over all manufacturer products, series or whatever. But it MUST be unique for a given P/N from a particular manufacturer.

This come from my experience in traceability (requirement engineering, material configuration management, BOM, logistic and so on).